# Передача значения в main

Tags: java

```
public class StringMassive {

    StringMassive helper = new StringMassive();

    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        //helper.receiver(String s); ошибка
        }

    public void massive() {
        String[] names = {"Антон", "Дмитрий", "Пётр"};
            helper.receiver(names[0]);
    }

    public void receiver(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Застрял на ерунде, пожалуйста подскажите. У меня есть массив из имен, находящийся в методе `massive()`. Я выбираю из массива нулевой элемент `Anton` и передаю его методу `reciver(String s)`. Как я могу получить элемент Anton в методе `main`?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь объявить экземпляр класса String в параметре метода. Или же я не понял вашей задумки ?

Comment: Я пытался передать аргумент `names[0]` в метод `reciver`. Чтобы метод принял его, я должен объявить параметр это метода типа String (такой же как и передающийся аргумент `names[0]`). Поэтому я написал `String s`. Можно обойтись без этого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 способ

```
static Main helper = new Main();

public static void main (String[] args) {
    helper.massive();
}

public void massive() {
    String[] names = {"Антон", "Дмитрий", "Пётр"};
    receiver(names[0]);
}

public void receiver(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

2 способ

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    massive();
}

public static void massive() {
    String[] names = {"Антон", "Дмитрий", "Пётр"};
    receiver(names[0]);
}

public static void receiver(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

3 способ

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    new Main().massive();
}

public void massive() {
    String[] names = {"Антон", "Дмитрий", "Пётр"};
    receiver(names[0]);
}

public void receiver(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Очень непривычно вызывать методы без какой-нибудь ссылки. Это нормальная практика?

Comment: @KojerDefor ссылки на что? ты про `this`? если да, то нельзя ссылаться из статического контекста(метода в данном случае)

Answer (score 1):

Код в вопросе - не рабочий. `StringMassive helper = new StringMassive();` приведет к бесконечной рекурсии создания новых объектов `StringMassive`. Сделайте `helper` локальной переменной в `main`:

```
public class StringMassive {

  public static void main (String[] args) { 
    StringMassive helper = new StringMassive();

    System.out.println(helper.receivedValue);
    helper.massive();
    System.out.println(helper.receivedValue);
  }

  public void massive() {
    String[] names = {"Антон", "Дмитрий", "Пётр"};
    this.receiver(names[0]);
  }

  public String receivedValue;
  public void receiver(String s) {
    this.receivedValue = s;
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Переменная `helper` не статична, я не могу вызвать её из метода `main`. А, если я засуну объект в метод main, то метод `massive` не сможет воспользоваться ссылкой `helper`.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так вы же вызываете метод *receiver*, вызовите *massive()*, он Вам и выведет, что вы хотели.